# VS Code estensions don't work in Ubuntu

Tags: visual-studio-code

hello guys i have a problem, when i download this background extension in vs code a message pops that says [image: this] and then after i retry with admin [image: it says this]
tho when i try on windows i get no problems , i did research about it a lot but couldn't find anything useful to help me , can sm1 help that would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Install VSCode from a deb, not by a snap.

Comment: hello mate , you mean by deb as terminal ?

Comment: It doesn't matter how you install the deb. Download it and install.

Comment: okay my friend i really appreciate your help ill try it and see if its going to work !!

Comment: thanks g it did work !!

Answer (score 1):

There are limitations when using VSCode installed by a snap.

I suggest removing the snap and installing it from a deb file.

You can download it form https://code.visualstudio.com/